# Можно ли установить кнопку для запуска WhatsApp на сайте

Tags: html

Есть ли возможность запуска чата WhatsApp со своей картинкой? Если да, то какое?

Comment: Что значит со своей картинкой

Comment: Ну со своей картинкой которая размещена на сайте. В одном дизайнерском решении.

Comment: Ну через iframe

Comment: А чего-то поискал в инете не нашёл, неужели нет возможности повесить запуск приложения для связи с другим пользователем?

Comment: Просто у скайпа просто всё решено

Comment: У телеграм нашёл решение, а вот у вотсапа нет

Comment: Ну пользователь как минимум должен зарегистрироваться в whatsapp

Comment: Это понятно )))

Comment: Скорее всего это невозможно даже средствами php

Comment: Нашёл решение, но оно только если человек заходит с андроида. ( https://leadinlife.info/knopka-whatsapp-dlya-sajta.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё оказалось проще.

```
<a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=1111111111" target="_blank" class="fa fa-viber" title="whats app"></a>
```

на месте  1111111111 номер телефона  на который вы хотите получать сообщения от пользователя вотсапа

Answer (score 2):

Открыть WhatsApp:

```
<a href="whatsapp://">Открыть WhatsApp</a>
```

Открыть WhatsApp и начать чат с номером XXXXXXXXXXX (без + в начале):

```
<a href="whatsapp://send?phone=XXXXXXXXXXX">Открыть WhatsApp</a>
```

Открыть WhatsApp и отправить сообщение "Текст сообщения":

```
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=Текст%20сообщения">Открыть WhatsApp</a>
```

**Также можно комбинировать.**

Открыть WhatsApp и начать чат с номером XXXXXXXXXXX с сообщением "Текст сообщения":

```
<a href="whatsapp://send?phone=XXXXXXXXXXX&text=Текст%20сообщения">Открыть WhatsApp</a>
```